# Get file name before the extension

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

I have some files in the same directory (in UNIX filesystem) that looks like:

```
a.txt.name
b.xml.name
c.properties.name

a.txt.name2
b.xml.name2
c.properties.name2
```

How do I get the string before the `name` or `name2` part using some shell command?

ie. the `a.txt`, `b.xml`, `c.properties` part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ basename a.txt.name .name
a.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ file="a.txt.name"
$ file="${file%.*}"
$ echo "$file"
a.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If naming convention is always *foo.bar.other* , then this is simple enough:

```
ls * | cut -d. -f1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the bash string manipulation functions. This page should get you most of the way there:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html